# Replicate default mouseover background color when a button is pressed

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am building a wpf ribbon application.  When certain buttons are clicked on, I would like the background to remain "lit up" like when the mouse is over it.  I don't want to change the default mouseover color, I just want to replicate it when the button is pressed for "modal" type commands.  Is there a way to do this?  In MFC programming it would be like adding the "BS_PUSHLIKE" style to the button where it remains lit while active.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are looking for, but I believe the equivalent of "BS_PUSHLIKE" in WPF is the [ToggleButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.aspx) control.

Comment: Yes, and for the ribbon specifically, the "RibbonToggleButton".